# Debugging distributed OR operation

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

I am trying to perform a bitwise operation on integer arrays stored in different nodes of a distributed system. After computing the results I want to distribute the result to every node. For accomplishing this I am trying to use MPI_Allreduce operation. But I am getting runtime errors with the following code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int numtasks, taskid, n=200, i;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);

    int *arr;
    arr = new int[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) arr[i] = 0;
    for(i=taskid; i<n; i+=numtasks) arr[i] = 1;

    MPI_Allreduce(arr, arr, n, MPI_INT, MPI_BOR, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(taskid == 0){
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The program is working correctly when n is 1 but when n>1 it is giving the following error during runtime.

> [user:17026]  An error occurred in MPI_Allreduce
> [user:17026]  on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
> [user:17026]  MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer
> [user:17026]  MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
>
> ---
>
> mpirun has exited due to process rank 2 with PID 17028 on node user
> exiting improperly. There are two reasons this could occur:
>
> 1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits for
>    all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
>    then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.
> 2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize". By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
>    exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"
>
> This may have caused other processes in the application to be
> terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).
>
> ---
>
> [user:17025] 3 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal
> [user:17025] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages

I want to know does MPI_Allreduce works with n>1 or not because most of the examples available on the internet have taken n as 1 only. If my approach is completely wrong, please suggest me a better solution for my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the same buffer for sending and receiving, you can specify `MPI_IN_PLACE` as send buffer.

```
MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, arr, n, MPI_INT, MPI_BOR, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Note: This works only for intra-communicators. `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is an intra-communicator. If you don't know what an inter-communicator is, your communicator is probably an intra-communicator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the MPI library, but from the MPI_Allreduce documentation:

> int MPI_Allreduce(const void *sendbuf, void *recvbuf, int count,
>                     MPI_Datatype datatype, MPI_Op op, MPI_Comm comm)

I would guess that the "const void *sendbuf" and "void *recvbuf" **HAVE** to be different arrays, even more so in an heavily parallelized computing I suppose.

It would not surprise me that the library check if the two pointers are at the same address or overlap, hence the message:

> [user:17026] MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer

So the code would be something like this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int numtasks, taskid, n=200, i;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);

    int *arr_send = new int[n];
    int *arr_recv = new int[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) arr_send[i] = 0;
    for(i=taskid; i<n; i+=numtasks) arr_send[i] = 1;

    MPI_Allreduce(arr_send, arr_recv, n, MPI_INT, MPI_BOR, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(taskid == 0){
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", arr_recv[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Not a lot of difference from the original. Let me know if that works for you.